# The xxx outlet of 'File's Owner' is connected to 'Label YYY' but xxx is no longer defined on zzz

Tags: build, xcode3.2

All of a sudden I'm getting over a hundred warning messages of that sort out of XCode build (that used to build without any warnings), but, curiously, when you look at the connections in Interface Builder there's no problem, buttons that are reported to lack connections work fine, and in every other way the application seems normal.

It's happening with several different view controllers and XIBs, some of which have some some stuff in common, but one which is entirely different from the others, with no includes in common, no common interfaces (other than Apple's), etc.

I tried clean, and I tried deleting the entire build directory, to no avail.  Looked for files that may have gotten dragged out of place in the XCode file listing, but nothing obvious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved: Apparently someone in our group is using a later version of IB and checked in the XIBs. They're semi-incompatible with 3.2 until they're edited once, then the warnings go away.